# Can I call jsp file inside ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, jsp

My Project contains several JSP files and Spring MVC. If I use ReactJS, is it simple to include whole JSP file inside JS like:

```
render: function() {

        return (
            <a href="page.jsp">link</a>
        );
}
```

?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is **No**

`Reactjs` is a client side language,and `JSP` are sever side language,you can not include a server side page to client side page,due to the server do not know which client is!